# Installing ingress nginx on Minikube with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

In all tutorials I see on Minikube and ingress-nginx, it says you should run:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Which basically applies an ingress controller and all of the related stuff. However, lets say you use helm or helmfile, and you want to install your ingress nginx from there, to make your cluster consistent with production. What would you do then? conditionally apply the ingress-nginx in production only and enable the ingress addon locally? or should it work perfectly fine if you install ingress-nginx from helm locally, without enabling the ingress addon? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an ingress controller the normal way in minikube, and indeed, you should if you want to replicate what you are intending to do in production.

`minikube addons enable` is just an easier way to do this but is minikube-specific. And since you're not going to be running minikube in production (not normally, anyway) if you want to reproduce the workflow you will use in production, don't use `minikube addons enable`.

Side note: you'll probably need to have `minikube tunnel` running, in order to get IP addresses for your minikube services.

Comment: From what I noticed, installing ingress-nginx without the ingress addon results in strange behavior - sometimes I manage to access my services and sometimes not, even though minikube tunneling is activated. It doesn't seem to happen when ingress addon is enabled.

Comment: If you have multiple ingress controllers in the cluster, make sure to specify different ingress classes otherwise, they'll be fighting over the traffic and that could be the "sometimes able, sometimes not" scenario

Comment: I didn't mix the two together, I made sure the ingress addon was disabled, but still when I installed from helm it was flaky.

Comment: I can't say I've ever had a "flaky" minikube service endpoint myself. Is it every service or just one?